# C++ - separating header and implementation files

Tags: c++

So, I have created this code, but I am having hard time separating the files. So far when I create the header file it works fine, but when I create the .cpp files for dctorType, patientType and billType it says undefined, and the header file personType is redefined. Please help

```
#include <iostream>

#include <string>

using namespace std;

// Base class personType

class personType

{

public:

void print()const;

//Function to output the first name and last name

//in the form firstName lastName.

void setName(string first, string last);



string getFirstName()const;

string getLastName()const;

personType(string first = "", string last = "");

//Constructor

//Sets firstName and lastName according to the parameters.

//The default values of the parameters are null strings.

//Postcondition: firstName = first; lastName = last  

private:

string firstName; //variable to store the first name

string lastName; //variable to store the last name

};

void personType::print() const

{

cout << "Person FirstName="<<firstName << " LastName=" << lastName<< endl;

}

void personType::setName(string first, string last)

{

firstName = first;

lastName = last;

}

string personType::getFirstName() const

{

return firstName;

}

string personType::getLastName() const

{

return lastName;

}

//constructor

personType::personType(string first, string last)

{

firstName = first;

lastName = last;

}

// --------------------Start your code from here

class doctorType: public personType

{

public:

// doctorType(string first,string last,string special);

void print()const;

void setSpeciality(string special);

string getSpeciality() const;

doctorType(string first, string last, string special);

//private:

string firstName; //variable to store the first name

string lastName;

string speciality;

};

void doctorType::print() const

{

cout << "Doctor FirstName="<<firstName << " LastName=" << lastName<< " Speciality="<<speciality<<endl;

}   

void doctorType::setSpeciality(string special)

{

speciality = special;

}

string doctorType::getSpeciality() const

{

return speciality;

}

doctorType::doctorType(string first, string last,string special)

{

firstName = first;

lastName = last;

speciality = special;

}

class patientType:public personType

{

public:

patientType(string first="", string last = "", int id1=0,int age1=0,int dob1=0);

void setId(int id1);

void setAge(int age1);

void setDob(int dob1);

int getId() const;

int getAge() const;

int getDob() const;

void print() const;

//private:

string firstName;

string lastName;

int id;

int age;

int dob;

};

patientType::patientType(string first,string last,int id1,int age1,int dob1)

{

firstName = first;

lastName=last;

id = id1;

age = age1;

dob = dob1;

}

void patientType::setId(int id1)

{

id = id1;

}

int patientType::getId() const

{

return id;

}

void patientType::setAge(int age1)

{

age = age1;

}

int patientType::getAge() const

{

return age;

}

void patientType::setDob(int dob1)

{

dob=dob1;

}

int patientType::getDob() const

{

return dob;

}

void patientType::print() const

{

cout << "Patient FirstName="<<firstName << " LastName=" << lastName<< " Id="<<id<<" Age="<<age<<" Dob="<<dob<<endl;

}  

class billType

{

public:

billType(doctorType &d,patientType &p);

void setCharge(double chrg);

double getCharge() const;

void print() const;

private:

double charge;

string patient_first;

string patient_last;

int patient_Id;

int patient_Age;

int patient_Dob;

string doctor_first;

string doctor_last;

string doctor_speciality;

};

billType::billType(doctorType &d, patientType &p)

{

//double charge;

patient_first = p.firstName;

patient_last = p.lastName;

patient_Id = p.id;

patient_Age = p.age;

patient_Dob = p.dob;

doctor_first = d.firstName;

doctor_last = d.lastName;

doctor_speciality = d.speciality;

}

void billType::setCharge(double chrg)

{

charge = chrg;

}

double billType::getCharge() const

{

return charge;

}

void billType::print() const

{

cout << "Patient FirstName="<<patient_first << " LastName=" << patient_last<< " Id="<<patient_Id<<" Age="<<patient_Age<<" Dob="<<patient_Dob<<endl;

cout << "patient's Doctor FirstName="<<doctor_first << " LastName=" << doctor_last<< " Speciality="<<doctor_speciality<<endl;

cout<<"Hospital charges="<<charge<<endl;

}

//--------------------driver program

int main()

{



personType person1("Lisa", "Regan");

doctorType doctor1("Sarah", "Conner", "Dentist");

patientType patient1("Sam", "Fire",200,100,1916);

billType b1(doctor1, patient1);

b1.setCharge(250.66);

cout << "<personType> Printing...\n";

person1.print();

cout << endl;

cout << "<doctorType> Printing...\n";

doctor1.print();

cout << endl;

cout << "<patientType> Printing...\n";

patient1.print();

cout << endl;

cout << "<billType> Printing...\n";

b1.print();

cout << endl;

return 0;

}
```

Comment: You will have to show how you separated the files and how you included the header file into your cpp file.

Answer (score 0):

The personType header goes as follows:

```
#ifndef PERSONTYPE_H
#define PERSONTYPE_H
#include <string>


using namespace std;

class personType
{
public:

    void print()const;
    //Function to output the first name and last name
    ////in the form firstName lastName.
    void setName(string first, string last);
    string getFirstName()const;
    string getLastName()const;
    personType(string first = "", string last = "");
    ////Constructor
    ////Sets firstName and lastName according to the parameters.
    ////The default values of the parameters are null strings.
    //Postcondition: firstName = first; lastName = last
    string firstName; //variable to store the first name
    string lastName; //variable to store the last name

};
#endif
```

The only change I made was making firstName and lastName public instead of private. (And added header guards, which are very important.)

I wont be showing every file as they're almost identical and I will let you do the work.
Here is the BillType.h:

```
  #ifndef BILLTYPE_H
    #define BILLTYPE_H
    #include <string>
    #include "patientType.h"
    #include "doctorType.h"

    class billType

    {

    public:

        billType(doctorType &d,patientType &p);
        void setCharge(double charge);
        double getCharge() const;
        void print() const;

    private:

        double charge;
        string patient_first;
        string patient_last;
        int patient_Id;
        int patient_Age;
        int patient_Dob;
        string doctor_first;
        string doctor_last;
        string doctor_speciality;

    };

    #endif
```

Since we included both patient and doctor, which in turn include person, we only need to include billType.h into our driver.
The driver is almost identical to what you have right now. In your method 'billType' in your driver, I would recommend using your getters instead of calling the variables directly. I would also recommend using an Initializer list in your constructors.

The important thing to remember is that if you want to include a custom header file, use `#include "filename.h"`.